# org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Error -118 {error,access_rules_unauthorized}

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api

I m trying to get the response of `get_roster` in ejabberd through XML-RPC client but I am using ejabberd 18.9 version and it is showing me this error:

> org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Error -118 A problem
>   '{error,access_rules_unauthorized}' occurred executing the command
>   get_roster with arguments
>   [{user,<<"admin">>},{server,<<"localhost">>}]

Can somebody suggest how can I solve this?

Here is my  java client code:

```
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
  config.setServerURL(new URL("http://localhost:4560"));
  XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
  client.setConfig(config);
  Hashtable<String, Object> params = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
  params.put("user", new String("admin"));
  params.put("server", new String("localhost"));
  List<Object> roster_params = new ArrayList<Object>();
  roster_params.add(params);

  Object result = client.execute("get_roster", roster_params);
  System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have ejabberd configured in a way that you must provide auth details of an account with admin rights. In this example written in python, see the LOGIN structure. Sorry, I don't know how this is done in Java.

```
import xmlrpclib

server_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:4560'
server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(server_url)

LOGIN = {'user': 'admin', 'server': 'localhost', 'password': 'mypass11', 'admin': True}

def calling(command, data):
    fn = getattr(server, command)
    return fn(LOGIN, data)

print ""
print "Calling with auth details:"
result = calling('get_roster', {'user':'user1', 'server':'localhost'})
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is now resolved there was some issue with the ejabberd.yml file.
I enabled outh configurations after removing this in config file now this codes works...

port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/api": mod_http_api